# Multiple Project Gradle Setup with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have two gradle projects. Project A includes Project B as a dependency.  I have them both imported into intellij,   With the same setup using maven,  I could update project B and run Project A would immediately see the changes. With gradle I must run gradle build on project B and then refresh project A in intellij.  Is there a trick to make this more dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If A and B were part of the same multi-project build, you could have A import B in this way:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':B')
}
```

Then, changes to B should immediately be visible to A. In other words, a change in B might cause a failed build in A as soon as IntelliJ detects that A is out of date and builds it.

However, it sounds like this is not the case, so A is actually importing B from some remote repo?

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.stackoverflow.example:B:1.12"
}
```

In the later case, when Gradle (or IntelliJ) compiles project A, it actually uses the version of B which is in your local gradle cache, or towards the remote repo. Either way, Gradle won't see changes made in B until those changes are built and published to the repo.

Comment: Yes,  what you said is all true,  but what I am looking for some way to tell intellij not to use the local gradle cache.  The source code with the same version qualifier is present in the same intellij project.   I have tried removing the dependencies source location of the .m2 cache and pointing it to the local source but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In project A's build.gradle, how have you defined the dependency?